# Get from SQLite DB email and score of a user and send the score to each user respectively

Tags: android, sqlite

I have created an application in Android that needs to send emails to all contacts saved in the database as you click on a SendMailbutton, to sending email to each contact with respective score,

the idea was to slide the couples (email,score) of each user in the database and pass it to a specific method that sends the email

I implemented the send method in order to receive the email address and the score associated
I tested the send eMail method and works properly,

The only problem is that I can not define a way suitable for
pass all the email address and the associated scores of each user at the click of the button.

**My DatabaseHelper class is the follow:**

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;




public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

static final String dbName="demoDB";
static final String PlayerTable="Players";
static final String colID="PlayerID";
static final String colName="PlayerName";
static final String colEmail="Email";
static final String colScore="Score";
static final String colDept="Dept";

static final String deptTable="Dept";
static final String colDeptID="DeptID";
static final String colDeptName="DeptName";

static final String viewEmps="ViewEmps";


public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, dbName, null,33);

    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+deptTable+" ("+colDeptID+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , "+
            colDeptName+ " TEXT)");

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+PlayerTable+" ("+colID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
            colName+" TEXT, "+colEmail+" TEXT, "+colScore+" Integer, "+colDept+" INTEGER NOT NULL ,FOREIGN KEY ("+colDept+") REFERENCES "+deptTable+" ("+colDeptID+"));");


    db.execSQL("CREATE TRIGGER fk_empdept_deptid " +
            " BEFORE INSERT "+
            " ON "+PlayerTable+

            " FOR EACH ROW BEGIN"+
            " SELECT CASE WHEN ((SELECT "+colDeptID+" FROM "+deptTable+" WHERE "+colDeptID+"=new."+colDept+" ) IS NULL)"+
            " THEN RAISE (ABORT,'Foreign Key Violation') END;"+
            "  END;");

    db.execSQL("CREATE VIEW "+viewEmps+
            " AS SELECT "+PlayerTable+"."+colID+" AS _id,"+
            " "+PlayerTable+"."+colName+","+
            " "+PlayerTable+"."+colEmail+","+
            " "+PlayerTable+"."+colScore+","+
            " "+deptTable+"."+colDeptName+""+
            " FROM "+PlayerTable+" JOIN "+deptTable+
            " ON "+PlayerTable+"."+colDept+" ="+deptTable+"."+colDeptID
            );
    //Inserts pre-defined sections
    InsertDepts(db);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+PlayerTable);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+deptTable);

    db.execSQL("DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS dept_id_trigger");
    db.execSQL("DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS dept_id_trigger22");
    db.execSQL("DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS fk_empdept_deptid");
    db.execSQL("DROP VIEW IF EXISTS "+viewEmps);
    onCreate(db);
}

 void AddPlayer(Player emp)
{


     SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();


    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();

    cv.put(colName, emp.getName());
    cv.put(colName, emp.getEmail());
    cv.put(colScore, emp.getScore());
    cv.put(colDept, emp.getDept());
    //cv.put(colDept,2);

    db.insert(PlayerTable, colName, cv);
    db.close();


}

 int getPlayerCount()
 {
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cur= db.rawQuery("Select * from "+PlayerTable, null);
    int x= cur.getCount();
    cur.close();
    return x;
 }

 Cursor getAllPlayers()
 {
     SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();



     //Cursor cur= db.rawQuery("Select "+colID+" as _id , "+colName+", "+colEmail+","+colScore+" from "+PlayerTable, new String [] {});
     Cursor cur= db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+viewEmps,null);
     return cur;

 }

 Cursor getAllDepts()
 {
     SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
     Cursor cur=db.rawQuery("SELECT "+colDeptID+" as _id, "+colDeptName+" from "+deptTable,new String [] {});

     return cur;
 }

 void InsertDepts(SQLiteDatabase db)
 {
     ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
        cv.put(colDeptID, 1);
        cv.put(colDeptName, "Sales");
        db.insert(deptTable, colDeptID, cv);
        cv.put(colDeptID, 2);
        cv.put(colDeptName, "IT");
        db.insert(deptTable, colDeptID, cv);
        cv.put(colDeptID, 3);
        cv.put(colDeptName, "HR");
        db.insert(deptTable, colDeptID, cv);
        db.insert(deptTable, colDeptID, cv);

 }

 public String GetDept(int ID)
 {
     SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();

     String[] params=new String[]{String.valueOf(ID)};
     Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT "+colDeptName+" FROM"+ deptTable+" WHERE "+colDeptID+"=?",params);
     c.moveToFirst();
     int index= c.getColumnIndex(colDeptName);
     return c.getString(index);
 }

 public Cursor getEmpByDept(String Dept)
 {
     SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
     String [] columns=new String[]{"_id",colName,colEmail,colScore,colDeptName};
     Cursor c=db.query(viewEmps, columns, colDeptName+"=?", new String[]{Dept}, null, null, null);
     return c;
 }

 public int GetDeptID(String Dept)
 {
     SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
     Cursor c=db.query(deptTable, new String[]{colDeptID+" as _id",colDeptName},colDeptName+"=?", new String[]{Dept}, null, null, null);
     //Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT "+colDeptID+" as _id FROM "+deptTable+" WHERE "+colDeptName+"=?", new String []{Dept});
     c.moveToFirst();
     return c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("_id"));

     }

 public int UpdateEmp(Player emp)
 {
     SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
     ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
     cv.put(colName, emp.getName());
     cv.put(colScore, emp.getScore());
     cv.put(colDept, emp.getDept());
     return db.update(PlayerTable, cv, colID+"=?", new String []{String.valueOf(emp.getID())});

 }

 public void DeleteEmp(Player emp)
 {
     SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
     db.delete(PlayerTable,colID+"=?", new String [] {String.valueOf(emp.getID())});
     db.close();



 }

}
```

Help me please.

Comment: need more insight of your database structure to make a correct solution

Comment: Ok, I have updated my question adding the DatabaseHelperClass.

Any suggestion??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create getScores returning HashMap in your dbHelper class

   ```
   public HashMap<String,String> getScores() {
   HashMap<String,String> list = new HashMap<String,String>();
   SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
   Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("Select email,sum(score) from players group by Email",null);
       if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
           do {
               list.put(cursor.getString(0),cursor.getString(1));
           } while (cursor.moveToNext());
       }
       if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
           cursor.close();
       }
   return list;}
   ```
2. use this method to send emails assuming

`sendMail(String mailTo,String score);`

---

```
HashMap<String,String> scores = dbHelper.getScores();
for(Map.Entry entry : scores.entrySet())
{
     sendMail(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue());
}
```

---

hope this helps to clarify it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have tried to use your code in the apps but crash, I'm not sure but the error seems related to: 

`Cursor cursor = getDB().rawQuery("Select email,sum(score) as score from players group by email,score",null);` 


In the debugger is shown the error  "no such column: email"

Are you sure this code is correct??

Comment: use Email :))) select. It looks like it's case sensitive. Because I was looking at your table to create the query.

Comment: It is not the case it means either the fields of the table or the table are not created. I've updated the select try it. If you will get the same error you should really check into how you create the table and if it gets created at all.

Comment: I have yet tried to change the word "email" with "Email" (and score with Score)... but there is the same crash... "no such column: Email" :(

Comment: have you taken look at the database and the tables? do they have all the information and needed fields?

Comment: The database should works because is correctly viewed in the app.

Comment: OK I've set your db instead of my getDB() this should fix it.

Comment: I have tested It and now works fine. THANKS! THANKS! THANKS!!